# In C# 3.5, How do you pass which method to call on an object as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, delegates, refactoring

I have two methods in C# 3.5 that are identical bar one function call, 
 in the snippet below, see clientController.GetClientUsername vs clientController.GetClientGraphicalUsername

```
    private static bool TryGetLogonUserIdByUsername(IGetClientUsername clientController, string sClientId, out int? logonUserId)
    {
        string username;
        if (clientController.GetClientUsername(sClientId, out username))
        {
           // ... snip common code ...
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool TryGetLogonUserIdByGraphicalUsername(IGetClientUsername clientController, string sClientId, out int? logonUserId)
    {
        string username;
        if (clientController.GetClientGraphicalUsername(sClientId, out username))
        {
           // ... snip common code ...
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Is there a way (delegates, lamda's ?) that I can pass in which method on clientController I want to call?

Thanks!

Comment: The sample is an instance of a generic problem I've encountered when refactoring blocks of code that are identical bar different methods calls.  In particular, I seem to see these in tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Just define a delegate like so:

```
public delegate bool GetUsername(string clientID, out string username);
```

And then pass it into your function and call it:

```
private static bool TryGetLogonUserId(IGetClientUsername clientController, string sClientId, out int? logonUserId, GetUsername func)
{
    string username;
    if (func.Invoke(sClientId, out username))
    {
       // ... snip common code ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

To call the function with the delegate, you'll do this:

```
TryGetLogonUserId(/* first params... */, clientController.GetClientUsername);
```

Comment: What are you saying is poor style? Passing in the delegate? I was just answering the question. Calling ".Invoke()" on the delegate? I prefer that notation because it makes it clear that you are using a delegate.

Comment: I'm with Josh G, this seems quite an elegant solution to the problem, and if you name "func" carefully its clear what is happening

Comment: I agree with Josh G. There's absolutely nothing "poor" in calling Invoke on a delegate instance.

Answer (score 9):

While you can pass a delegate as a parameter, I suggest going with a different route. Encapsulate the body of the `if` statement which involves common code in another function and call that one in both functions.

Visual Studio has a "Refactor `->` Extract Method" feature in the context menu. You can just fill in one of the bodies, select the body and use that feature to extract a method out of it automatically.

Comment: I agree, a redesign would be better.

Comment: I also agree: Redesign! That's a typical case where you start complicating things that are simple. KISS.

Comment: This is perfect advice for programming in an imperative style (especially if there are only two possible functions), but actually passing the function allows for a pretty decent emulation of the functional-language feature of partial application.

Comment: @Mark: I agree that this style makes sense in functional languages but C# is not a pure functional language. While LINQ and lambdas are really great and add a functional sense to the language, it *doesn't replace the imperative aspects* of C#. I don't see any reason to sacrifice simplicity of the language when the imperative style is more suited.

Answer (score 1):

The type of a function is written as Func < inParam1, inParam2, ..., returnParam>.  I'm not sure offhand if "out" parameters are passed properly in "Func" types, but you should be able to make your function like

```
void TryGetLogon(Func<IGetClientUsername, string, out int?, bool> f) { 
   // ...
   f(x, y, z, a);
}
// ...
TryGetLogon(TryGetLogonUserIdByGraphicalUsername);
```

Comment: "out" and "ref" are not legal in type arguments. You'll have to define a new delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx), which can be looked up statically.  However, I agree that a redesign may be called for.

```
private static readonly MethodInfo getRegularLogin = typeof(IGetClientUsername).GetMethod("GetClientUsername");
private static bool TryGetLogonUserIdByUsername(IGetClientUsername clientController, string sClientId, out int? logonUserId)
{

    string username;
    return TryGetLoginReflective(getRegularLogin, clientController, sClientId, out username, out logonUserId);
}

private static readonly MethodInfo getGraphicalLogin = typeof(IGetClientUsername).GetMethod("GetClientGraphicalUsername");
private static bool TryGetLogonUserIdByGraphicalUsername(IGetClientUsername clientController, string sClientId, out int? logonUserId)
{
    string username;
    return TryGetLoginReflective(getGraphicalLogin,  clientController, sClientId, out username, out logonUserId);
}

private static bool TryGetLoginReflective(MethodInfo method, IGetClientUsername clientController, string sClientId, out string username, out int? logonUserId)
{
    object[] args = new object[]{sClientId, null};
    if((bool)method.Invoke(clientController, args))
    {
         // ... snip common code ...
    }
    logonUserId = ...;

    username = (string)args[1];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: A delegate is a much better way to go about this than reflection.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply passing in a boolean flag?

```
private static bool TryGetLogonUserIdByUsername(
    IGetClientUsername clientController,
    string sClientId, out int? logonUserId, bool graphical)
{
    string username;
    bool gotClient = false;

    if (graphical)
    {
        gotClient = clientController.GetClientGraphicalUsername(
            sClientId, out username);
    }
    else
    {
        gotClient = clientController.GetClientUsername(
            sClientId, out username);
    }

    if (gotClient)
    {
               // ... snip common code ...
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good idea; although I prefer the delegate approach - less code to communicate the same intent

Comment: When given the option, I prefer to avoid boolean flags like this.  They move functional description of the function you're calling from the function name to the parameter list.  (In this case, the end of the parameter list).  Also, the meaning of the boolean isn't apparent at the callsite-- you have to look up the parameter name to figure out what it means.